# Unable to click on WebApp Element with Selenium due to dynamic iframe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following external HTML for the blue "Stampa fiscale" button I am trying to click on within a private web app:

```
<a id="cdgxo_Stafisc_image" class="imageIconBox boxAzureCircle Stafisc_image_ctrl" href="javascript:cdgxo. Stampa()" target="_self" title="Stampa fiscale modelli F24"></a>
```

[image]

I tried with:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="imageIconBox boxAzureCircle Stafisc_image_ctrl"]').click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cdgxo_Stafisc_image"]')
```

But none of them seem to be working; namely, the following exceptions occur:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: [class="imageIconBox boxAzureCircle Stafisc_image_ctrl"]
```

and:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="cdgxo_Stafisc_image"]
```

In more detail, the aforementioned button is within a dynamic iframe, described as:

```
<iframe spparentobjid="etiveixwbp_MyVersamenti_bvuza_container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ps-stretch-height="" name="../jsp/gsmd_container.jsp?containerCode=VERSAM&amp;pTitle=Versamenti" id="MyVersamenti_bvuza_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="../jsp/gsmd_container.jsp?containerCode=VERSAM&amp;pTitle=Versamenti" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Specifically, the id changes according to the word in bold *"MyVersamenti_**bvuza**_iframe"*

A workaround I've found to find the iframe of interest is the following:

```
html_page = driver.page_source.split(" ")
hoi = [elem for elem in html_page if ("MyVersamenti_" in elem) & ("_iframe" in elem)]
iframe = hoi[0].split('"')[1]
```

Is there an alternative (more pythonic) solution?

Comment: Maybe the page hasn't loaded completely. Try adding a ```time.sleep()``` before this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the iframe and then click the element.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@id, 'MyVersamenti_')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Stampa fiscale modelli F24']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a#cdgxo_Stafisc_image[class='imageIconBox boxAzureCircle Stafisc_image_ctrl']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If above code returns timeout exception then please check if any `iframe` available above the element you are targeting in DOM tree.

---

**Update:**

To handle iframe Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='MyVersamenti_'][id$='_iframe']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a#cdgxo_Stafisc_image[class='imageIconBox boxAzureCircle Stafisc_image_ctrl']"))).click()
#jump out from iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: How to I check the available iframes? @KunduK

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli : If you could post the html of the `Iframe` you are targeting?

Comment: please check the comment given to the previous answer; the iframe name changes dynamically at every login

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli : Check the updated answer and let me the status?

Comment: it returns a timeout; please check the edit to the question to better frame the issue; many thanks

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli : Just updated can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

Item you are trying to reach is inside iframe
try:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('Path to iframe')

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Item is not loaded for that you can use wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cdgxo_Stafisc_image"]')))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cdgxo_Stafisc_image"]')))
```

Comment: The above-mentioned code returns a timeout exception; how can I find the iframe of interest within the Html page?

Comment: follow the tag in reverse you will find iframe tag

Comment: Unfortunately, the iframe dynamically changes at every login; namely, it is called "MyVersamenti_" + a_code_that_always_changes(e.g. biyqw) + "_iframe"; for xpaths, I found a workaround as "driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, '_Stafisc_image')]"
                                  )"; how can I do that with iframes?

Comment: Can you share source code of website here?  I am not sure what you mean by iframe changing dynamically, iframes are suppose to change what you need is iframe id or class or if there is only one iframe you can simply use (‘//iframe’)

Comment: Please check the edit for the code; thank you so much

Comment: How many iframe are there on page? Can you check by using driver.find_elements_by_xpath(‘//iframe’) you will get all the i frames on page if there is only one you wont need id or class..

Comment: Here is a tip while using selenium webdriver use terminal to test your code.. you can go like driver = webdriver.Chrome() once browser is open navigate page manually once you get there test your code in terminal, it will save you a lot of time running’s script over and over and getting exception

Answer (score 0):

In order to click an element inside of an iFrame, you need to use the `driver.switch_to.frame(element)` method. To do this, you need to create a method that allows you to switch to your iFrame. For this example, I used the [W3Schools iFrame Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) website.

**Method: Switch to iFrame**

```
def switch_to_iframe(self, xpath : str):
        element = self.chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        self.chrome_driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```

**Action Method: Click tab inside of iFrame**

```
def click_javascript_tab_in_iFrame(self):
        # Goes into our iFrame
        self.switch_to_iframe("//iframe[@title='W3Schools HTML Tutorial']")
        
        # Searches for our element inside of our iFrame and clicks on it
        self.chrome_driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='topnav']//a[contains(@class, 'w3-bar-item') and text()='JAVASCRIPT']").click()

        # Waits until a certain element loads
        self.wait_displayed("//div[@id='main']//h1[contains(., 'JavaScript') and contains(., 'Tutorial')]")

        # Gets out of the iFrame and returns to the parent window
        self.chrome_driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

For your `html` element example

```
<iframe spparentobjid="etiveixwbp_MyVersamenti_bvuza_container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ps-stretch-height="" name="../jsp/gsmd_container.jsp?containerCode=VERSAM&amp;pTitle=Versamenti" id="MyVersamenti_bvuza_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="../jsp/gsmd_container.jsp?containerCode=VERSAM&amp;pTitle=Versamenti" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

you could use the following `xpath` since it does not really care about the full id tag.

```
//iframe[contains(@id, 'MyVersamenti') and contains(@id, 'iframe')]
```